# How to differentiate between tokens generated from client credential flow and authorization grant flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My apis will be consumed from other external api(s) as well as external client applications.  My api(s) need to know how they are being consumed. I am planning to use the Access Token provided to access the API to find out out if the api is being called from another api or client application.  My access token could be generated from client credential grant flow as well as authorization code grant flow .

When the api receives the token how can it find out the token has been generated by the client credential flow or authorization grant flow ?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, token created using both client credential flow and authorization grant flow works exactly the same way from a technical side.

The most important difference is that in client credential token 'may' have less features 'tagged' to it. These features depends on how your authorization server is handing your token creation request.

For eg: in spring security, you can configure that certain logged in(authorization or ROPC grant) users can have the scope as "read create update", where as an anonymous user(client credential) can have only "read" scope. The provider app can then decide whether to use this 'scope' or just ignore it and process both request in same way or not.

Most of the API gateways in the industry has its own way of handling these. For example, in Tibco mashery, there is a 'user context' apart from'scope, which can be used very well to separate authentication and authorization.

**Answering your question..** It depends.. On what API gateway and authentication you use and how your authorization server is creating Authorization grant and client credential tokens.. (I dont know much about Azure)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `azp` field in the token for now. It usually refers to the Client Id for the App that requested it. It is not present in a Authorization grant flow.
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html